# Ordering x-axis on correlation heat map using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a correlation heat map using ggplot, but I cannot seem to control the order of my variables on the x or y axis.  Specifally, ggplot seems to try to order the variables sequentially, but only operating on the first digit.  Here's a simple example of the problem

```
x1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

x2<-c(1,2,3,3,5,4,6,7,4,4,6,3,4,5,6,10,8,9)

x3<-c(2,2,3,5,5,4,6,4,4,4,6,3,4,5,6,10,8,9)

x4<-c(1,2,3,5,5,4,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,10,8,9)

x5<-c(1,2,3,3,5,4,6,7,4,4,6,3,4,5,6,10,8,9)

x10<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,1,4,5,1,1,1,1)

new=data.frame(x1)

new$x2=x2

new$x3=x3

new$x4=x4

new$x5=x5

new$x10=x10

keep=melt(cor(new))

ggplot(keep,aes(Var1,Var2),xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue")+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

If you run this code you'll see that the x-axis is ordered

```
x1, x10, x2, x3, x4, x5
```

whereas I want it to read

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x10
```

Is there a way to specify this order?

Comment: Please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) so others know that your question was answered, and so the folks that helped you get some recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if the padded zero solution doesn't fit for your purpose:

```
cust_breaks<-unique(keep$Var1[order(as.numeric(gsub("x","",keep$Var1)))])

ggplot(keep,aes(Var1,Var2),xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=cust_breaks) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits=cust_breaks)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
keep$Var1 <- factor(keep$Var1, levels = unique(keep$Var1), ordered = TRUE)
keep$Var2 <- factor(keep$Var2, levels = unique(keep$Var2), ordered = TRUE)

ggplot(keep,aes(Var1,Var2),xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue")+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I end up with `length(keep$Var1)`, or 36, ordered levels for `keep$Var1` and warnings using this code. You shouldn't specify greater than `length(unique(keep$Var1))` levels in `factor`

Comment: Yes I get warnings too, what do they mean?

Comment: They mean you have duplicated `levels` in the factor, which is not right - type `keep$Var1` and you can see that you have 36 repeating levels, when you only need 6.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. I've edited my answer and now get no warnings and the correct number of levels.

Comment: You're probably still better off explicitly specifying the order. At the moment you're relying on the luck of the draw that the values of `keep1/keep2` are in the right order in the `keep` dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, one option would be to name your variables `x01`, `x02`, etc and then they will order correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Troy's answer I wrote a small function:

```
reorder_version_sorting <- function(col,prefix){
  unique(col[order(as.numeric(gsub(prefix,"",col)))])
}
```

Usage:

```
ggplot +...+
      scale_x_discrete(limits=reorder_version_sorting(dd2$Rep,"rep"))
```

Before:

```
"rep0"  "rep10" "rep11" "rep12" "rep13" "rep14" "rep15" "rep16" "rep17" "rep18" "rep19" "rep1"  "rep2"  "rep3"  "rep4"  "rep5"  "rep6"  "rep7"  "rep8"  "rep9"
```

After:

```
"rep0"  "rep1"  "rep2"  "rep3"  "rep4"  "rep5"  "rep6"  "rep7"  "rep8"  "rep9"  "rep10" "rep11" "rep12" "rep13" "rep14" "rep15" "rep16" "rep17" "rep18" "rep19"
```